# Searching With Apostrophe

Tags: query, search, mysql

I'm having trouble with my custom theme's search function. I have a number of posts with apostrophes in the title. For example, `McDonald's`.

However, when I try searching say `McDonalds`, the post won't return in the search results.

How can I go about making sure that `McDonald's` would return in the result even if the user didn't include the apostrophe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't much of a WordPress related question, more like a MySQL question.
But I have sort of a solution in my head:

You could go with a custom query and a replace on the apostrophe:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE REPLACE( `column`, "'", "") LIKE REPLACE( 'string', "'", "" )
```

For a combined search:

```
SELECT *, REPLACE( `column`, "'", "" ) AS `custom`
WHERE `column` LIKE 'string'
OR `custom` LIKE 'string'
```

It isn't worlds most beautiful solution, but you could give it a shot.